# User has not stopped voting fraud/plagiarism. Has anything been done about it?

Tags: support, moderation, fraud-voting

### Timeline:

1. Flagged [Assign the guest quote when customer login into the checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350985/assign-the-guest-quote-when-customer-login-into-the-checkout-page/369296#369296) on Aug 24, 2023, pointing out voting fraud and ChatGPT usage. The flag was marked as helpful, and the post was deleted the same day.
2. Flagged [Magento 1.9.4.2 Get orders with REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369281/magento-1-9-4-2-get-orders-with-rest-api/369291#369291) on same day for ChatGPT and plagiarism. I neglected to mention voting fraud in this, but my prior flag was still pending when this flag was raised. Handled on Aug 30.
3. Flagged [Magento 2.4.6 Opimize database tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369419/magento-2-4-6-opimize-database-tables/369436#369436), raising the issue again on Aug 29. Deleted Aug 30.
4. Flagged [Magento 1.9.4.2 Get orders with REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369281/magento-1-9-4-2-get-orders-with-rest-api/369498#369498) on Aug 31 for reposting the plagiarism. Deleted Sep 12.
5. **User keeps posting**, well after prior flags were handled. **Secondary account keeps upvoting.** User's answers: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/112638/grazitti-dev?tab=answers.
6. User has again posted [an answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/369922/) on Sep 26 to the sockpuppet account's question.
7. User has [reposted](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/369954/) the deleted answer from #1 on Sep 27.

### What has been done about this?

At the point of handling flag 1, it seems pretty apparent that [this user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/92141/sunil-sharma) is the one behind the voting fraud, with an upvote and accept coming in shortly after posting. Yet, while the ones I specifically flagged were deleted, [all of these answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/112638/grazitti-dev?tab=answers) still exist and have their votes. Both user accounts still exist, and neither is suspended.

- Has this at least been escalated to the CMs? I understand that CMs are busy, and it takes time, and they are the ones that have to reverse votes or merge accounts. However, they need to at least be notified if they haven't been.
- Has the user at least been notified that voting fraud and plagiarism are not acceptable? If so, **why has neither user been suspended** on the second (or third) offense? If they have not been notified, why not?

**Why is nothing, beyond individual post deletions when I flag, being done about this?**

Answer (score 1):

if there is a voting fraud normally Mod can see voting fraud in few scenarios

I will not discuss all scenarios here.but yes few certain level mod can see

normally Marius always delete the account from user doing upvotes and suspend main account for a month to doing any activity at the website

this actions send strong message that you can not do fraud upvoting.

there are some scenarios which is not highlight in mod tools so they cannot take actions for those scenarios.

I cannot confirm those scenarios as I am not a mod till now, but I am posting this answer whatever I know from **Marius** and **Amit bera**

Comment: Er... sorry. I meant for you to address this topic in your election questionnaire. (Just as a helpful example to bolster your point.)